# Calculating the average are of an annulus and the unit circle

Tags: integration, area, average

I'm trying a problem and came across the following problem. Choose a point at random uniformly from $\overline B_1(0)$, let's say $x$. Fix some $t_1,t_2\in\mathbb R^+$, what's the average area of the intersection of the annulus of inner radius $t_1$ and outer radius $t_2$ centered at $x$ with $B_1(0)$. I know that if $f(x,y)$ is the area of said annulus centered at $(x,y)$ then the value I'm looking for is
$$\frac1\pi\int_{B_1(0)}f(x,y)\;dA=\frac1\pi\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^1rf(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\;drd\theta$$}
but I'm having trouble actually computing $f$. Could you help me? If it makes the calculations easier, in my particular problem I have $t_1=t-\varepsilon$ and $t_2=t+\varepsilon$ for some fixed $t\in(0,1)$ and $\varepsilon\in(0,t)$

Comment: As $(A\setminus B)\cap C=(A\cap C)\setminus(B\cap C)$, the area of the intersection with the _annulus_ is the difference of the areas of intersection with the corresponding _discs_ (of radii $t_1$ and $t_2$). By linearity of expectation, the average intersection with the annulus will then be the difference of the average intersections with the discs. So the problem is reduced to the average area of intersection with a _disc_.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I know, but that problem seems equally as hard. I have been trying that to no avail